# Access Domino Server from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, lotus-domino

I picked up this project which used XML to access a domino server and returns data to a asp.net page. I know nothing about Domino.

The code that it is failing on is

```
objRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(NSGlobal.User, NSGlobal.Password, NSGlobal.Domain);
            objRequest.PreAuthenticate=true;
            objRequest.Timeout = 1200000;
            objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
```

It fails on the last line and goes to the catch block. The catch error is "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I have validated that the user, password and domain are valid. I am stumped. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved. I replaced the web.config with a more recent one. I'm not sure why the difference, but I'm happy it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

not knowing much about the Domino APIs and seeing that your code seems to be mostly ok, I would play around with the properties of the objRequest to see if anything important has not been set yet.

see also this question: [send email C# smtpclient using ibm lotus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101281/send-email-c-smtpclient-using-ibm-lotus) especially the answer where he explains that sometimes the order in which properties are set does matter!

this might also help: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lotusnoteintegrator.aspx